# PowerBI Embedded Link Filter

Tags: powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

is there any way we can filter the POWERBI dashboard by passing the column values inside the link (Publish To Web)?

if not a staright forward way then any workaround?

tried to filter the dashboard by passing the column values in the POWERBI link (Embed to Website or Portal) it works fine but not for the link (Publish To Web)

Answer (score 0):

Filtering a report using query string parameters in the URL is not supported in 'Publish to web'

Refer to the https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#embedding-scenarios

As per your question, the option of 'Publish to web' is not available for Power BI dashboard. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web